# Cassandra-CQl : Change Clustering order for Created Column Family

Tags: cassandra, cql

I know that I can define clustering order when I create a table by cql as code below:

```
create table test(
id int,
time timestamp,
value text,
primary key(id,time)) with clustering order by (time desc)
```

but I want change the clustering for table test after its creation with alter:

```
alter table  test
with clustering order by (item asc)
```

but I got error by that.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 18):

Changing the clustering order would require rewriting all your data on disk in a different order.  The standard way to do this is to leverage Spark with the Cassandra Spark Connector: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Alternatively, if you're early in your dev process or it's a relatively small amount of data, you can use the bulk loader to throw it into a new table: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I assume this is still valid in recent versions of Cassandra? And is there an easy way to bulk-load?

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm a little surprised that this is still useful 8 years later.  I've edited it with links to some tools that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You may also change your CQL SELECT query to ORDER BY ASC without altering the table.